# Spark: filter out all rows based on key/value

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD, x, in which I have two fields: id, value. If a row has a particular value, I want to take the id and filter out all rows with that id.

For example if I have:

```
id1,value1
id1,value2
```

and I want to filter out all ids if any rows with that id have value value1, then I would expect all rows to be filtered out. But currently only the first row is filtered out because it has a value of value1.

I've tried something like

```
val filter = x.filter(row => (set contains row.value))
```

This filters out all rows with a particular value, but leaves the other rows with the same id still in the RDD.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply a filter function for each rdd row and the function after the `=>` should include the row as Array whether or not it includes that token idx or whatever. You might have to adjust the number of the token , but it should look something like this ( whether you should use contains or not contains depends on whether you want to filter in or filter out:

```
val filteredRDD = rawRDD
  .filter(rowItem => !(rowItem.map(_.toString).toSeq
  .contains(rowItem.(0).toString)))
```

or even something like:

```
 val filteredRDD = rdd1.rawRDD(rowItem => !(rowItem._2 contains rowItem._1))
```